# Is there any well-defined, measurable atomic size?

Tags: atomic-physics, measurements

Is there any well-defined, measurable size at the atomic scale?  I was under the impression that the van der Waals radius was a good way of describing the size of an atom, but it turns out to be a much fuzzier concept.

Comment: well, at atomic scales QM kicks in, which means there isn't really any well-defined lenght (well, except maybe wavelenght of monochromatic light...). The *size* of an atom is a fuzzy concept *per se*.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, that's what I was afraid of.  In that case, you might as well make that an answer.

Comment: Crystal lattice constants are very well defined and measurable with high precision and so are electron distributions. If one accepts that atoms are field objects with many internal degrees of freedom and that they have to be measured like fields, their "mechanical dimensions" are necessarily just as well defined as the frequencies of their optical transitions. What size means is simply not a single number but an infinity of them, but that's already the case for macroscopic objects. How "tall" is a tree?

Comment: @CuriousOne the Bohr radius is also very well defined and measurable with high precision. The issue is that the radius of the atom is not very well defined, even though $a_0$ is ($a_0$ is **not** the radius of the atom). Lattice constants are very well defined, but the spacing of the lattice is not, just like the case of the atomic radius ($a,b,c$ are **not** the lenghts of a hypothetical cuboid of the lattice)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Which brings me back to my question: how tall is a tree, really? It's an object with many branches, which one am I using? Am I adding the roots? Do I need to measure on a rainy day or when the tree is very dry? If we ask the right question, then we get good answers (like the lattice constants that are extremely well defined in x-ray crystallography), if we ask inadequate question, then even a tree doesn't have a size. The problem is not one of atomic physics, it's one of proper definitions for all systems.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the state is for atoms, but for nuclei (which are just as much quantum mechanical) there are several "usual" choices that one might make. Things like "full width containing 90% of the charge" or the neutron scattering hard-core radius, and these things have different values, but of course you chose the one that is most appropriate to your needs.

Comment: Nuclei are subject to the saturation of nuclear forces which gives a certain predictability to their sizes that doesn't apply to atoms.